# ruby 2.0 not work well with rails3.2.8: can not load js and css file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-2.0

My app is using ruby1.9.3 and rails3.2.8, toady i install ruby2.0 in my new pc. i tried to run

```
    rails s
```

it runs without js and css files required in application.js / application.css loaded.

how can ruby2.0 works well with rails3.2.8?

Comment: the app is ok using ruby1.9 and rails3.2. i think this error is not connected with application.html.erb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 3.2.13 is the first release of rails designed to work with ruby 2.0.0.

In addition rails 3.2.8 has critical security holes being actively exploited - you really should upgrade.

Comment: really thanks. i have upgraded. i will find more details about this question.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue my app was not loading any of the files (css, js) located on the assets folder, but upgrading rails from 3.2.8 to 3.2.13 (and other gems using "bundle update" command) fixed the issue, so thanks Frederick Cheung!